# Why does converting date to_char() throw ORA-01830 error when placed in a case-then?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, plsql

I have been using this code for a long time, and it works fine:
`to_char(v_emailRow.first_stamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy')`

However, today I needed to add the following condition
`case when v_cardCode = 'C1' then v_date else to_char(v_emailRow.first_stamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy') end`.

As soon as I added the case-then statement, whenever the to_char() needed to be executed, it began always throwing `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string` error. If I remove case-then, it works as usual, if I add it back, the error immediately returns.

I have tried writing a test script, googling, but I cannot find the issue. The same value is being converted in both cases, why does one of them work and the other throws an error?

Comment: We would need DDL for your table as well as some sample data to be able to replicate the error.  But to guess at this, I would suspect v_date might be a date variable.  So then your CASE would be attempting to return a mix of DATE data types and CHAR data types which would cause problems.  Try with a TO_CHAR on v_date?

Comment: @Stilgar you are correct, v_date is a date variable. Very likely that's the issue, didn't think of that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when v_cardCode = 'C1' then v_date else to_char(v_emailRow.first_stamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
>
> whenever the to_char() needed to be executed, it began always throwing ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string error

`v_date`, as the variable name suggests it's a `DATE` data type, while applying `TO_CHAR` converts date to a `STRING`. Therefore, having two different data types is causing the error.

Try below `CASE` in your SQL:

```
case 
  when v_cardCode = 'C1' 
  then to_char(v_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  else to_char(v_emailRow.first_stamp, 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
end
```